# Store WP state on phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, serializable

I want to store the state of the app on the phone to recreate it when the app starts again.

The problem is that I need to store things like `IDictionary<string, object>` that includes all kind of types. Is there any good way to do this?

I don't want to do it for every type manually, like I am doing now. I am converting every type to json, and save it as a string. I currently need a file system on the phone like

```
MyApp \\ JObjects \\ asd.json
MyApp \\ Dictionary_string_int \\ asd2.json
```

...etc., so I can get the type of the original object later on and can call

`Deserialze< IDictionary<string, int> >(..)` for example

And that's very painful. Every time I want to store a new type, I have to implement a method for that first and test it. And objects like `IDicionary< string, IDicitionary<string, object>>` are particulary painful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Isolated Storage to save and read your deserialized XML into separate files. Check out this tutorial on using it:

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-xml-files

The article is for WP7, but it also works in WP8. I think it's referred to as Local Folder now in WP8, but the code should work the same.